# Proof of the Direction of Heat Flow

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I’m reading Callen's thermodynamics book and he proves that heat tends to flow from a system with a high temperature to a system with a low temperature by assuming the temperature difference of two systems is infinitesimal.

Callen added that the conclusion is also true without the assumption. I tried to prove this by integrating 
$$dS=\left(\frac{1}{T_1}-\frac{1}{T_2}\right)dU_1,$$
but I cannot proceed anymore. How does the same conclusion hold without the infinitesimal assumption? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that the entropy change of an isolated system in which a hot body is equilibrated with a cold body is positive?

Comment: I have the same question as Chet. The second law does not "prove" that heat flows naturally from a high temperature system to a low temperature system and not the other way around. It was needed to explain why the reverse direction was never observed in nature and yet the relevant existing law at the time of conservation of energy would allow heat to flow either way. So you are probably trying to prove that the second law would not permit the reverse direction. Right?

Comment: @ChetMiller Chet, do you want to take this one?

Comment: @Bob D Let's wait for the OP's clarification.

Comment: @ChetMiller Agree. BYW does the PF have a chat feature like the Exchange? I want to return to our problem, but I am still grappling with the initial conditions of the two equations. I think chat would be a better format for discussion than a post.

Comment: @BobD What you do is start a conversation.  To do this, you click on the logo of an envelope on the top tool bar.

Comment: @ChetMiller I'm sorry for asking vague question. I want to prove that the heat flows from a high $T$ to low a low $T$ for an isolated system by using the maximum entropy postulate; the values assumed by the extensive parameters in the absence of an internal constraint are those that maximize the entropy over the manifold of constrained equilibrium states.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment above, suppose we let $\Delta U$ represent the change in internal energy of the initially cold body, $T_H$ represent the final temperature of the initially hot body, and $T_C$ represent the final temperature of the initially cold body.  Then, from the first law of thermodynamics, $$\Delta U=M_CC_C(T_C-T_{0C})=-M_HC_H(T_H-T_{0H})\tag{1}$$From this equation, in terms of $\Delta U$, the masses, heat capacities, and initial temperatures, what are $T_H$ and $T_C$?

Let $S_{0H}$ and $S_{0C}$ represent the initial entropies of the hot body and cold body, respectively.  Then, in the final state of the system, the entropy of the system will be:
$$S=S_{0H}+M_HC_H\ln{(T_H/T_{0H})}+S_{0C}+M_CC_C\ln{(T_C/T_{0C})}\tag{2}$$
What is the value of $\Delta U$ which maximizes S, what is its sign, and how do the values of $T_H$ and $T_C$ compare in this state?  Also, what is the change in entropy at this maximum?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I agree with @Chet Miller's answer. However, based on your follow up comment to him, the following is simply offered as another perspective.

To simplify your “proof”, and since you are specifically interested in proving that heat flows only from high temperature to low temperature based on the second law, consider assuming there is no work transfer between 1 and 2 ($dW=0$). Assume also that the masses of body 1 and 2 are great enough that the differential transfer of heat occurs isothermally (at constant temperature for both). Then $dU=dQ$ and your equation becomes, for a differential transfer of heat $dQ$ between body 1 and body 2:

$$dS_{tot}=\biggl(+\frac{dQ}{T_1}-\frac{dQ}{T_2}\biggr)$$

Now, the second law says the total entropy of the system plus the surroundings must be equal to or greater than zero. Then, considering the two bodies as comprising the system and surroundings we have

$$dS_{tot}=dS_{1}+dS_{2}≥0$$

Therefore

$$dS_{tot}=\biggl(+\frac{dQ}{T_1}-\frac{dQ}{T_2}\biggr) ≥ 0$$

When heat transfers out $dS$ is negative (reduction in entropy) and when heat transfers in $dS$ is positive (increase in entropy). In terms of the signs you chose, that would mean that $T_2$ is the high temperature body (heat transfers out) and $T_1$ is the low temperature body (heat transfers in).

Since the same amount of heat, $dQ$ transfers into body 1 and out of body 2, energy is conserved and the first law is satisfied. But the first law would also be satisfied if $dQ$ transferred out of body 1 (low temperature body) and into body 2 (high temperature body), yet that has never been observed and thus the need for the second law.

Now looking at the last equation what is $dS_{tot}$ if $T_{1}>T_{2}$, that is, if  $dQ$ flowed out of the cold body and into the hot body? Would that satisfy the second law?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The temperature depends on $U$.

$$\Delta S = \int dU^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{T^{(1)}(U^{(1)})}-\frac{1}{T^{(2)}(U^{\rm tot}-U^{(1)})}\right)$$

Comment: Yes, I understand that $T$ depends on $U$. But how can I prove that $\Delta U$ is negative if $T_1>T_2$?

Answer (score 0):

For the following at equilibrium,

$$dS=\left(\frac{1}{T_1}-\frac{1}{T_2}\right)dU_1$$

and, from the definition of equilibrium, i.e,

$$dS=0$$

for arbitrary values of $dU_1$ it implies

$$\frac{1}{T_1}-\frac{1}{T_2}=0$$

or

$$\frac{1}{T_1}=\frac{1}{T_2}$$

You can use $\Delta S$ and $\Delta U_1$, but the point is the system is in equilibrium, and from definition of equilibrium, $\Delta S=0$, and $\Delta U_1$ is arbitrary.